# window.scrollTo in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

location = element.location

size = element.size

driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,location['y'])")`

when i put a number in scroll it works.
however this code does not give me any error but doesn't work either

Answer (score -1, accepted):

when you write `driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,location['y'])")` you are passing the entire string, as it is to the method `execute_script`.

What you should be doing instead is to construct your script as

```
scroll_script = "window.scrollTo(0, %s)" % str(location.get('y'))
driver.execute_script(scroll_script)
```

Edit:

you can also use this as

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0])", location.get('y'))
```

Can i ask you to look into the javascript function `scrollIntoView`? [W3School reference](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_scrollintoview.asp)
This function Scrolls the element into the visible area of the browser window

example:
`driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView()', element)`

Comment: can i scroll to desires x and y?
because when i put:
driver.execute_script(location.get('x'), location.get('y'))
it doesn't work and can i apply this function to pages without scrollbar???

Comment: tanx again just its arguments not argument